# Probability that you get a composite number both times when rolling a six-sided die

Tags: probability

Suppose you roll a standard six sided dice twice. What is the probability that you get a composite number both times?

Considering that $4$ and $6$ are the only composite numbers that we have here, the probability of getting a composite number both times should be $2/6 \times 2/6 = 1/9$. Right? Well, the correct answer is $1/4$. How though?

Comment: Are you sure about the composite number? If you rephrase the question to "not a prime number", then $\frac{1}{4}$ is correct, as $1$ is neither prime nor composite.

Comment: The question explicitly asks 'a composite number both times'. But I guess you make a valid point here. Maybe they are counting 1 as a composite number here.

Comment: @Dominique I see that you've flagged an answer below because you don't like that they made an answer out of your comment. I've dismissed that flag. I'll also note that if you wanted reputation for your answer, then [**don't answer in the comments**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36246/9754). Comments are ephemeral and may be deleted.

Comment: @Gram You say "correct answer". According to what?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the author is *incorrectly* taking $1$ to be a composite number. With that assumption, the probability would be $1/2 \times 1/2 = 1/4$.

Or as *Dominique* says, you would want to make sure the question actually says "a composite number" and not "not a prime number". They do not mean the same thing. $1$ will fail the former criterion but pass the latter.